# Instantiating model objects and linking view with model objects in Qt: where should this happen?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, model-view

In Qt, the typical style for a QWidget-inheriting class is to have a setupUi() method which instantiates child objects. The UI is thus pieced together by composing child QWidget objects in parent QWidget objects in a hierarchical fashion.

I'm trying to get away from defining global singleton model objects (e.g. one giant Data class singleton). However, there is still needs to be shared model state which is accessed at multiple points and multiple levels within the UI composition hierarchy (QWidget objects within QWidget objects). the child layers of the hierarchy in the composition are instantiated by upper levels, sharing state without a singleton would seem to require passing the necessary pieces of model state up and down setupUi functions all over the hierarchy upon startup.

This seems way more complicated than it should be. What's the correct approach here?

Comment: setupUi() is typical style for a designer form, it isn't typical style for instantiating QWidget classes although it doesn't hurt to have a helper class that creates QWidgets. I think the question is more of a coding design question for passing around a data object within multiple classes, for which, a singleton class is one solution. I don't think you'll find a 'right' solution to this question.

Comment: What kind of models are you talking about? Can you provide a code sample of your issue to clarify it?